# RegEx not recognizing decimal number well

Tags: php, regex, decimal-point

I am trying to obtain a number with a decimal point using regex, i have this string where the number in question is

```
RewriteRule ^additem/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$additem.php?price=$1
```

However if I enter 2.02, the stored variable is .02. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You miss a space at the border between your pattern and the replacement. I think you need `RewriteRule ^additem/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$ additem.php?price=$1`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  a space between the pattern and the replacement, and use a capturing group around the whole float value pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^additem/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$ additem.php?price=$1
                     ^       ^^            ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD7gZ3/2)